# Concurrent static context

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, static

I'd like to understand how static context work in multithread env.
If you have a static method in a class, lets say "ContainerClass.notSafeStaticMethod();" and you call it from different threads at the same time.

Are the variables inside the method shared?

```
public class ContainerClass{
    public static String notSafeStaticMethod(String stringParameter) {

        String localString = stringParameter + "1";
        localString += "2";
        localString += "3";

        return localString;
    }
}
```

Then two threads call it at the same time:

```
  ContainerClass.notSafeStaticMethod( "first Call"); /*Thread 1 is executing*/
  ContainerClass.notSafeStaticMethod( "Second Call"); /*Thread 2 starts executing before thread 1 finishes*/
```

What would happen with the internal state of the function? also, What would happen with the value of the parameter received?

Will be one different value for each or they share the same memory?

According to my understanding static variables are not in the stack but the heap, so they should share them and hence the code wouldn't be thread safe, Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables declared inside the static method are not static variables, they are local variables, and they are on the stack for that thread (though reference variables point to locations on the heap), in a stackframe dedicated to a specific method call. So there is no opportunity for other threads to interfere, each method invocation is isolated.

Now if there are static variables used by a static method then those can be accessed concurrently. static variables are declared in a class using the keyword static. So make sure you can identify static variables.

Btw, nested classes can be marked as static, that means only that objects of that class don't have a reference back to an object of the class they're declared as nested inside of (see java.util.Map.Entry for an example). `static` in this context doesn't mean variables or methods in the class are static. That's just the Java implementers reusing an existing keyword so they don't risk breaking pre-existing code.

```
public class Example {

    static int staticVariableHere;

    public static int staticMethodHere(String methodArg) {
        int localVariable = 42;
        return localVariable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Local variables are isolated. This includes method parameters. Each thread has its own stack and local variables related to method calls in that thread are stored on that thread's stack memory.

So, for method `notSafeStaticMethod`, neither of the 2 threads will see the other's (local variables') values or be able to manipulate them, regardless of the relative timing of the two calls.

Care is needed only for shared variables (for example, if `localString` is declared as static field in the class, or shared variables passed as method arguments), where threads can overwrite one another's changes unless proper synchronization is done.

Comment: I have a little confusion, I remember when I used restFul beans they should be instantiated by the context for each thread. Since they are restFul it would be more efficient to use a static class containing the common code. Then I don't understand the reason to use restful beans.

Comment: @DavidMarciel I assume you're referring to the static method. There's no problem with that. It's a method, not state. In other words, there's no chance for the two threads to interfere with one another's execution or data.